# NSIS disable Autorun at the end of the setup

Tags: nsis

I´m using NSIS editor to make a setup for my application, but I don´t want the user to have the option for Autorun the application.

I don´t want the checkbox at the last setup screen.

How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the iospecial.ini file of your NSIS directory. You can use this to customize your finish page. Here's one sample.. Check this out -> http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=264181